# How can i rename a branch/node in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have attached a picture, wherein i wish to rename the node during the run time for an application.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer:**

Currently, Firebase doesn't allow you to rename a node/branch. So you might delete that node and create a new node again.

Answer (score 2):

There is no api within Firebase for doing that. What can you do instead is to copy the information to another node and then simply delete the old one.

This is not a good practice to have the name of the product as a Firebase key. You need instead of using the product name, to use a unique identifier, an id. The best option is to use the unique key generated by the `push()` method. The name of the product will be then a child of your productId. Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- prducts_details
            |
            --- -Ki-k6fM5GTRpQhGBRFRa
            |        |
            |        --- productName: "product1"
            |
            --- -Ki-oAAtTG1bWzLvKD5L
                     |
                     --- productName: "product2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to Export the data. Once exported open and edit the exported.json. Here you can edit the node you want then save it and have Import to firebase db.